# How to compare many txt files in two different folders via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, compare, txt

I need to compare 27 txt files (which have identical names). They are in two separate folders and they have a lot of lines, when there are only one line different, I need that it writes out: "Files are Identical", as the line with date is every time different. The bonus would be that it will create new txt file with the results. I can run the powershell in the folder underneath are these two folders with the files to compare, so no special path is needed. Now I have it like this: but now it outputs: EQUAL DIFFERENT EQUAL lines

```
$report_before = Get-ChildItem "Report before XX3"
fc.exe $report_before[0].FullName $report_after | Tee-Object -FilePath "Compared_reports.txt"
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $report_before.Count; $i++) 
{$report_after = -join ("Report after XX3\", $report_before[$i].Name)
fc.exe $report_before[$i].FullName $report_after | Tee-Object -FilePath "Compared_reports.txt" -Append
}
```

Thank you.

I try to compare txt files in two folders with output in new txt file which will show if the files are identical or not.

Comment: You are not using any of the switches for [fc.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html), so question is: do you want ASCII or Unicode comparison? Case-sensitive or not?  Also, you do not show what _the line with date_ looks like and variable `$report_after` is undefined